# Trying to send e-mail using mail_admins() - got an error "Connection timed out"

Tags: django

My settings.py got parameters:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = "Sit_test@tut.by"
EMAIL_HOST = "tut.by"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "Sit_test"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "**********"
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And in my models.py i want to send e-mail to admins anytime SAVE button is clicked after editing an object:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def send_email_when_something_changed(**kwargs):
    mail_admins(subject="All systems nominal.", message="Dont worry!")
    print("Something has changed.")
```

But when i edit object and click SAVE - browser thinks for a while(a minute or to and i get an error "[Errno 110] Connection timed out"). Is there an error in settings or something is wrong with my signal handler?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your `EMAIL_HOST` setting?

Comment: Hmm..I guess it should be like "smtp.googlemail.com" and my EMAIL_HOST_USER should be Sit_test@tut.by. But still there's no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have a wrong EMAIL_PORT in settings.py - it has to be 587.